# Can a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra contain $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: ring-theory, transcendental-numbers

Is there a ring between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ that is finitely generated as an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$? My guess is there isn't.

I can see that it would have to be finitely generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ as well, and I think I can deal with algebraic generators. But if there are algebraically dependent transcendentals, I don't see how to exclude some rational. Why couldn't there be $\alpha$, $\beta$ transcendental, such for every prime $p$, $1/p$ is given by some integer polynomial in $\alpha,\beta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue fields of a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra (i.e. the quotients by maximal ideals) are *finite* fields (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341853)). There is no homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a finite field.

Comment: PS: We need no embedding to $\mathbb{R}$. So this has nothing to do with algebraic/transcendental numbers.

Comment: Well, that's the direction I was thinking, so feel free to remove the tag.